# Java garbage collector causes massive lags

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Every time, when the following message appears in the console, I notice a big lag in my game.

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 133693440 bytes, new threshold 7 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 916500K->130553K(918016K)] 1018868K->444063K(1232384K), 1.2505777 secs] [Times: user=1.87 sys=0.43, real=1.25 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 130553K->127049K(918016K)] [ParOldGen: 313509K->314172K(555008K)] 444063K->441222K(1473024K), [Metaspace: 9374K->9374K(1058816K)], 3.7134878 secs]
```

I run my program with the following arguments:

```
-Xms1024M
-Xmx2048M
-XstartOnFirstThread
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintClassHistogram
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
```

Is there any possibility to reduce the time which does the GC needs? How can I see the class of the objects, which are collected by the GC?

Comment: Which JVM version?  Which GC are you using (G1?)?  How much total heap memory do you allocate? (nm on that last one, I see you listed it right there.)

Comment: You have to do profiling and capture multiple heap dumps when you are seeing these GC events. Analyze those dumps and see the largest objects that are causing memory leaks. Then you can modify the code to fix the leaks.

Comment: These are baffling high pauses for such a small heap size. It’s also strange that the JVM does a pointless full gc after a young gc has already reclaimed a more than enough memory. Perhaps, using parallel gc is doing more harm than good for such a small heap. But anyway, since you seem to run under Java 8 or newer, just try a different gc algorithm, e.g. G1.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you're right, i use Java 8. Would it make a difference to use a higher Java version? 
I have tried to use G1, but it doesn't make any noticeable improvement. I think, there is any problem in my code which causes the issue and I have to do it like @RahulVedpathak suggested to find out the problem.

Comment: It’s hard to say whether a different Java version will change anything, when we don’t know the actual cause of the problem. I’d guess, the problem might be entirely unrelated to the JVM, caused by platform issues like swapping, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way to reduce the amount of time spent on garbage collection is to reduce the amount of garbage, plainly.

You can use a profiler like JvisualVM (comes with the JDK) to see exactly how your program uses the memory it's allotted and how much time is spent on garbage collection.

In the case of a game program, where you're going for a consistent frame-rate: you'll want to refactor your code such that objects are re-used as much as possible, rather than creating new ones and allowing them to be collected later (which will lead to noticeable lag-spikes whenever garbage collection is inevitably needed). (This is why memory-managed languages like Java aren't the best for games in particular, unfortunately.)

Comment: I found out that I create always new instances of a Vector class in my code. Would it be a possible way to have one or two static fields in every class for those Vectors to be able to re-use them?

Comment: @DasElias Possible--yes; but with respect to functional accuracy, I would suggest you open a separate question with more detail for an elaborate answer.